# AWS: Getting 400 Bad Request error from AmazonCloudWatch.GetMetricStatistics()

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, metrics, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm having a little trouble using AmazonCloudWatch to fetch CPU Utilization.  When I try to use AmazonCloudWatch.GetMetricStatistics(), I get this for an **exception message**:

> Exception of type 'Amazon.CloudWatch.AmazonCloudWatchException' was thrown.

And this for an **inner exception**:

> {"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."}

Here is the code I'm using to make the call:

```cs
public static String getCPUStats(String Endpoint, String InstanceID) 
    {
        try
        {
            AmazonCloudWatchConfig cloudConfig = new AmazonCloudWatchConfig();
            cloudConfig.ServiceURL = Endpoint;

            string AWSAccessKey = Sql.ToString(appConfig["AWSAccessKey"]);
            string AWSSecretKey = Sql.ToString(appConfig["AWSSecretKey"]);

            AmazonCloudWatch client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonCloudWatchClient(AWSAccessKey, AWSSecretKey, cloudConfig);

            GetMetricStatisticsRequest request = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest();
            request.Dimensions.Add(new Dimension { Name = "InstanceId", Value = InstanceID });
            request.StartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5);
            request.EndTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            request.Namespace = "AWS/EC2";
            request.Statistics.Add("Maximum");
            request.Statistics.Add("Average");
            request.MetricName = "CPUUtilization";
            request.Period = 60;

            GetMetricStatisticsResponse r = client.GetMetricStatistics(request);

            if (r.GetMetricStatisticsResult.Datapoints.Count > 0)
            {
                Datapoint dataPoint = r.GetMetricStatisticsResult.Datapoints[0];
                return "CPU maximum load: " + dataPoint.Maximum;

            }

            return "No data available.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Some side notes - the access key, secret access key, and endpoint work fine for creating an AmazonEC2Client, so I'm pretty sure the problem isn't there.

I've done quite a bit of googling and poring over the documentation, but haven't been successful in solving this.  Any ideas?  Thanks so much!

Comment: Part of the debugging challenge is that the "real" Amazon error message is getting lost in the AWSSDK and getting translated into a generic .NET 400 (aka: "BadRequest")... I'm fighting this same problem with some DynamoDB code... I think the only answer is to fire up Fiddler and look at the responses...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we weren't able to figure this one out - we ended up deciding to use Microsoft Azure instead of Amazon Web Services  :(

Comment: I'm starting to get the same idea. Not getting great help from forums or from email support. AWS wants you to pay and then I suppose I'll get help. I'm a developer trying to test and wanting to use AWS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only request one Statistics at a time. So try removing either `request.Statistics.Add("Maximum");` or `request.Statistics.Add("Average");`

Comment: I took out the "Average" one, but unfortunately, I got the same result  :(

Comment: Hmm..I am not very familiar with c# but can you check the startTime format and confirm that it looks like this 2012-06-02T10:00:00+08:00. if not change it into this format.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think I can do that because startTime expects a DateTime object, not a string - as far as I know, DateTime objects can't have formats (they just hold all the information).  Only DateTime-parseable strings can have formatting like that.  (let me know if I'm wrong on this, though)